# R modify value in one column if content in another column contains string

Tags: r

I am working with a large data set where I want to determine if a column containing text strings passes a logical test where I can subset it out later. Currently, I'm trying to build the test column for each row. The test is based on if the cell contains less than 2 relevant characters, but I want to keep the full set of characters in the actual cell. The following is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 1))
colnames(df) <- "test"
df$test <- c("one", "two", "three", "one", "onetwo")
df$hyp <- ("two", "one", "onetwo", "one", "two")
df$testcount <- sapply(df$test, str_length)
df$hypcount <- sapply(df$hyp, str_length)
df

    test    hyp testcount hypcount
1    one    two         3        3
2    two    one         3        3
3  three onetwo         5        6
4    one    one         3        3
5 onetwo    two         6        3
```

I want to identify a text string, like "two", and if a row in the `test` column or `hyp` column (depending on the test I'm running. I don't want this to run on both columns) contains the string (though is not identical to the string), then I want that same row to subtract the number of characters in the string I identified from the `testcount` or `hypcount` columns.

For example, if I run this function on the text string "two" in the `test` column, then I should get the following output:

```
    test    hyp testcount hypcount
1    one    two         3        3
2    two    one         0        3
3  three onetwo         5        6
4    one    one         3        3
5 onetwo    two         3        3
```

And if I were to run this on the `hyp` column, then I should get the following output:

```
    test    hyp testcount hypcount
1    one    two         3        0
2    two    one         3        3
3  three onetwo         5        3
4    one    one         3        3
5 onetwo    two         6        0
```

I have tried three approaches. First I tried using an if function to run the replacement conditionally (on this test I tested for the string "one" instead of "two"):

```
if(grepl("one", df$test)) {
  df[which(grepl("one", df$test)), ]$testcount = df[which(grepl("one", df$test)), ]$testcount - 3
  }
```

But this returns the warning: 
"In if (grepl("one", df$test)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

This leads to a correct substitution for the string "one", but not the string "two". Further, if I substitute for string "two" in the `hyp` column, the function works, but not if I run the substitution for string "one". I suspect this is because it only runs the test on the first row, and if it is true, then it checks the entire data frame.

Next I tried running the function within an lapply function:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {
  if(grepl("one", df$test)) {
    df[which(grepl("one", df$test)), ]$testcount = df[which(grepl("one", df$test)), ]$testcount - 3
  }}))
```

This also didn't work, though I don't fully understand why. Somehow it ends up returning the output:

```
  test hyp testcount hypcount
1    0   0         0        0
2    0   0         0        0
3    3   3         3        3
```

Lastly, I tried running it as an ifelse operation (here I switched to replacing for string "two" so I don't mistakenly think the function works on all rows):

```
df$testcount <- ifelse(grepl("two", df$test), (df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount = df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount - 3))
```

The strange thing is, this worked when I first applied it a few days ago. I tested it for the strings "two", "on", and "one", and it worked properly. Now, when I got around to applying it to my actual data, it didn't work. Further, when I went back to the testing to see what went wrong, it no longer is working. It simply returns the error:
  "Error in ifelse(grepl("two", df$test), (df[which(grepl("two", df$test)),  :
  argument "no" is missing, with no default"

I have tried two solutions to this. First, I tried adding a statement into the "no" argument that would have no impact on my data:

```
 df$testcount <- ifelse(grepl("two", df$test), (df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount = df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount - 3), T)
```

However, this causes it to return the output:

```
    test    hyp testcount hypcount
1    one    two         1        3
2    two    one         3        3
3  three onetwo         1        6
4    one    one         1        3
5 onetwo    two         0        3
```

Next I tried substituting a meaningful "no" argument:

```
 df$testcount <- ifelse(grepl("two", df$test), (df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount = df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount - 3), (df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount = df[which(grepl("two", df$test)), ]$testcount))
```

But now it returns the output:

```
    test    hyp testcount hypcount
1    one    two        -3        3
2    two    one         0        3
3  three onetwo        -3        6
4    one    one         0        3
5 onetwo    two        -3        3
```

I don't understand this output.

My question is, can anyone help me to understand why this is not working, and offer a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I want that same row to subtract the number of characters in the string I identified ". In your first example, `onetwo` contains the string `two`, so should you not be subtracting 6 (the length of `onetwo`) from `testcount = 6` to obtain zero?

Comment: OK, I see from your comment below that "the string" is the match string (two), not the matching string (onetwo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
subtract_match <- function(column1, column2, text, df) {
  df2 <- df
  df2[, column2] <- ifelse(grepl(text, df[, column1]), 
                           df[, column2] - nchar(text), 
                           df[, column2])
  df2
}

subtract_match("test", "testcount", "two", df1)

    test    hyp testcount hypcount
1    one    two         3        3
2    two    one         0        3
3  three onetwo         5        6
4    one    one         3        3
5 onetwo    two         3        3

subtract_match("hyp", "hypcount", "two", df1)

    test    hyp testcount hypcount
1    one    two         3        0
2    two    one         3        3
3  three onetwo         5        3
4    one    one         3        3
5 onetwo    two         6        0
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. Also, i can pull out the heart of the function and it should run faster, since it won't be a function call anymore.

    `df$testcount <- ifelse(grepl("two", df$test), df$testcount - nchar("two"), df$testcount)`

It's funny, my third approach was very close to the solution...Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem, but the following reproduces your expected outcome for the two test cases.

```
# The first argument is the column where you want to find id
# I'm unsure about what you want to subtract; subtracting the entry from 
# the count columns corresponds to setting the entry to 0
some_function <- function(col, id, df) {
    idx <- which(colnames(df) == col);
    df[df[, idx] == id, idx + 2] <- 0;
    return(df);
}

some_function("test", "two", df);
#    test    hyp testcount hypcount
#1    one    two         3        3
#2    two    one         0        3
#3  three onetwo         5        6
#4    one    one         3        3
#5 onetwo    two         6        3

some_function("hyp", "two", df)
#    test    hyp testcount hypcount
#1    one    two         3        0
#2    two    one         3        3
#3  three onetwo         5        6
#4    one    one         3        3
#5 onetwo    two         6        0
```

Also, you say *"contains the string (though is not identical to the string)"*, but for entries containing "onetwo" you do *not* subtract the count values. So it is complete matches that you are after?

Comment: Sorry, this function doesn't recognize that the string "two" is in row five of the `test` column, and change the value in row five of the `testcount` column to 3. 

The goal is to identify all instances of a text string in the `test` column, and subtract the length of that text (three in the case of the string "two") string from the value in the `testcount` column. Does that help?